# Starting to use APIs and would like some guidance

Tags: php, json, jet.com-apis

I am new to APIs and I would like to make a program to work with jet.com. Earlier in the year, Jet supplied a php client API, but then deleted it. How would i go about working with their current API that is in JSON?
I am comfortable with my php knowledge, but I do not know where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at php's `cURL` extention, or the `guzzle` wrapper around it. It allows to make comfortable http requests to arbitrary servers. If the result you get is in `JSON` format then you need to use `json_decode()` on it to get "normal" values you can use inside php. You will find _many_ examples for cURL usage.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks a lot man. I appreciate it!

Comment: Sure Welcome. You want to wrap your routines into a "client class" ultimately. Then, when you want to access the API from some application, you instantiate the object of that class and use it for the communication. That gives you a place to put configuration handling, caching, mode settings and whatever you need.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dsugarman/437c4c91aea86860ed13